# How can I make Christmas lights to put on a Christmas tree

Tags: modeling

I am wondering how to make Christmas lights in blender. They need to be simple, I am not going big for the cords, but I am focusing more on the lights.

I am fairly new to blender, so it will be a simple animation.

Comment: Please take a look at the meta for this site. According to this: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62/regarding-questions-and-answers-as-tutorials

Tutorial requests are outside the intended scope of StackExchange, including Blender's sub-exchange. There are plenty of tutorials out there, and that is not what this StackExchange is intended for.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a tutorial request. 

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with *[Modifiers](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers)*, E.g. an *[Array](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Array)* modifier and a *[Curve](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Curve)* modifier:

1. Create a stretch of wire with a light or two. The ends should be precisely placed so that the array modifier can merge them.

   2. To model such a basic lowpoly cable, you could add a *Circle* with `5` vertices:

      [image]

      Then:
   3. In edit mode, rotate `90` on the `X` axis (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>), then extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) it to both sides with increment snapping (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) so it is aligned to the grid:

      [image]
   4. Create two loop cuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) on either side of the middle edgeloop, then delete the middle edgeloop (<kbd>Delete</kbd>*> Edge loop*)

      [image]
   5. Scale the two top vertices apart (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>):

      [image]
   6. Extrude the two top faces up (<kbd>E</kbd>) and flatten by scaling to `0` (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>):

      [image]
   7. Extrude and scale in, extrude and scale up in a bulb shape, then merge (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>) the remaining vertices:

      [image]
2. add an *Array* modifier and enable *Merge*:

   [image]
3. Add a *Curve* modifier and set the *Object* to a curve object:

   [image]

---

Also see this tutorial on [Blender Cookie](https://vimeo.com/8088709)

Comment: Very helpful, but how do you make the lights

Comment: @JoshuaSlink You mean how to make it emit light when rendered?

Comment: No, I mean how did you model the strand of lights, and extrude a bulb shown in picture 1

Comment: @JoshuaSlink I'll come up with something better later, (my lightbulb is pretty bad) [This tutorial](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2009/12/12/modeling-a-set-of-christmas-lights-in-blender-2-5/) also has instructions on modeling Christmas lights.

Comment: @JoshuaSlink Updated answer

Comment: Those are some pretty strange looking tree lights :)

Answer (score 0):

If the lights are seen from a distance you could create a group of simple colored spheres and use them as emissions objects of a particle system. Then take the particle emitter (a cube will do) and send it in a path around the object you want to dress with lights (a tree for example). In the particle system properties turn off all the velocity and gravity so the particles remain locked to path of emitter.